# Emacs Icicles Space

Tags: emacs, icicles

I've gotten used to , when i press

`M-x`

that whenever i type a space, it gives me a hyphen and yet I'd like to use icicles, so is there a way to change it so that whenever i type space, it gives me a hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map   
 " " "-") 
(define-key minibuffer-local-must-match-map   
 " " "-")
```

source: http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/422e4297b9e4842d

Answer (score 0):

Just customize user option `icicle-completion-key-bindings`:

```
 M-x customize-option icicle-completion-key-bindings
```

By default, in that option value there is a binding of the space character key (printed as `SPC` but used as `" "` in key bindings) to command `icicle-self-insert` --- remove that binding entry.  You can also add a binding for the space key to option `icicle-word-completion-keys`, if you like.

However, my advice is to leave `SPC` as a self-inserting character (likewise, `?`).  Even vanilla Emacs has started to make a space char self-inserting, at least for file names...